# why my git can't push to my server by gitolite use git-daemon

Tags: git, gitolite, git-daemon

when I use gitolite, ignoring `git-daemon`, I can do like `git clone git://xxx/xxx`,but when I push the project, it shows me the error:

```
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Empty compile time value given to use lib at hooks/update line 6
remote: Use of uninitialized value in require at hooks/update line 7.
remote: Can't locate Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm in @INC (@INC contains:  /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at hooks/update line 7.
remote: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at hooks/update line 7.
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To git://www.54cxy.com/qianfuzi
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
```

However, when I use `ssh` like `git@xxx:xxx.git` it worked not only can clone, but also can push, but I want to use `git://` to clone and push, so what I can do for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is, if you are cloning a git repo managed by gitolite, that remote repo will contain a `post-update` hook ([reserved by Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#hooks)), which is supposed to be called by gitolite.

Normally, you should be able to push with the native git protocol, provided the repo is declared as readable by the user 'daemon' ([see syntax](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rules.html), and see "[Interfacing with `git-daemon`](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/external.html#umask)" for GitoliteV3)

```
repo @all
    R   =   gitweb daemon
```

> Any repo readable by the special user `daemon` is deemed to be readable by `git-daemon`.
>   For each of these repos, an empty file called `git-daemon-export-ok` is created in the repository (i.e., the `repo.git` directory inside `$HOME/repositories`).

So check if your gitolite.conf file does mention the user `daemon`, and if the file `$HOME/repositories/git-daemon-export-ok` is there.

Comment: but I want to use gitolite and git-daemon,so you can gitolite v3 Integrate git-daemon,and let git:// can do push ,not only clone?

Comment: @user1683012 I have edited my answer to address your specific request.

Comment: I touch git-daemon-export-ok in /home/git/repositories/qianfuzi  and in gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf is 
Repo qianfuzi
    WR+ = daemon
and it can clone git://www.xxx.com/qianfuzi but can't push it,
now use your method like
repo @all
    R   =   gitweb daemon
and put git-daemon-export-ok in repositories ,it can't clone and push,
when I clone it ,the error is
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /qianfuzi,
so what can I do for it,thank you

Comment: @user1683012 the `git-daemon-export-ok` must be produced by gitolite itself. Try to test it with a fresh gitolite installation and one test git repo, to see if that file is generated properly.

Comment: Think You VonC,I tried,but it don't worked and get the same error,my god,it is so trouble

Comment: @user1683012 just checking, are you using a gitolite V3? (not V2)